# Editing HTML code on window open

Tags: c#, html, edit

What I need is  in a window I want to open, there is this:

```
width="989" height="560"
```

And I want the width and height to be that of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you mean that the HTML of a web page you want to open contains a fixed width and height (indicated in your code snippet above).

Since the server doesn't know where the client's browser is on the screen, nor the size of the screen, it cannot specify the size of the page. Instead, you need to use Javascript to set the size and position of the browser window:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Maximuizing Window</title>
</head>
<body width="300" height="200">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>    
    <p>
        This page should maximize ... but only if its opened alone
        and not as part of browser window containing other open tabs.
    </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // When we move the window, make sure to take into consideration the 
    // available screen height to acommodate the taskbar.
    window.moveTo(screen.width - screen.availWidth, screen.height - screen.availHeight);

    // Resize the browser window to the available width & height:
    window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availWidth);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

HTH.

Comment: It's an embedded object with those settings, I need to edit the value in HTML.

I know you can change it with just editing the HTML because I tested using Chrome.

Comment: Sorry. I don't quite follow - you mean you want to edit the size of the page at runtime?